# Django -How do I set up a for loop using _set.all?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a for loop; however, I'm not really sure how to set it up properly. How do I set up a for loop properly to display all of my stored values in my db?

Right now in my template, I have it set up like so:

```
{% if comments %}
    {% for comments in post.comments_set.all %}
        {{ comments }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

There is no value return for {{ comments }}; however, when  {{ comments }} is placed outside of the loop, it returns the first comment.

Here are my views.py for this:

```
class PostList(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'articles/index.html'
    context_object_name = "news_posts"
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return newspost.objects.order_by('-post_date')[:5]

class PostComments(generic.DetailView):
    model = newspost
    context_object_name = "comments"
    template_name = 'articles/comments.html'
```

The models.py:

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "img/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class newspost(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    post_image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Published')
    post_short_description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    post_text = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
            return self.post

class PostComments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(newspost)
    comments_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comments_text = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.comment_text
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', views.PostList.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post'),
    url(r'^comments/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostComments.as_view(), name='comments'),
    url(r'^editors_request_form/$', views.EditorsRequestForm, name='editors')
)
```

I can't seem to find the proper way of setting the for loop up, I've tried a mulitude of things, but nothing seems to work. So how can I set up my for loop to return all of my {{ comments }}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the variable holding the `Post` object in the template is `object`.
Also, you cannot test the existence of the `comments` variable before your assign a value to it.

What you want to do is:

```
{% for comments in object.comments_set.all %}
    {{ comments }}
{% endfor %}
```

If there are no comments, nothing will be rendered as the loop will be empty. You may use [empty clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) to handle the case where there are no comments. Example:

```
{% for comments in object.comments_set.all %}
    {{ comments }}
{% empty %}
    The post has no comments.
{% endfor %}
```